# phoneGap camera image set in sencha touch container background

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch

I have to combine the phoneGap camera api with sencha touch.

i want to set background of container of sencha touch with image captured by camera api of phonegap.
Can any one give me some example or some idea?
Thanks

my Container

```
  ....
  {
   xtype: 'container',
   cls: 'SRCameraButton',
   flex:2,
   itemId   : 'photoBtn',
   action   : 'capture'
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that.

```
    var imageView = Ext.getCmp('imageView');
    Ext.device.Camera.capture({
        success : function(image) {             
            imageView.setHtml('<img src="data:image/png;base64,' + image
                    + '"width=200px height=200px />');

        },
        quality : 100,
        destination : 'data',
        source: source
    });
```

where **imageView** is container

```
    {
        xtype : 'container',
        id : 'imageView',
        width : 200,
        height : 200,
        style : 'margin: 0 auto'
    }
```